# Create a graph using python

Tags: python, graph

i have this data:

```
day_data = {
    '2023-10-16': [('11:23:35', '1'), ('11:23:40', '1'), ('11:23:45', '1'), ('11:23:50', '1'), ('11:23:55', '1')],
    '2023-10-17': [('11:23:34', '1'), ('11:23:42', '1'), ('11:23:45', '0'), ('11:23:50', '1'), ('11:23:55', '0')],
    '2023-10-18': [('11:23:35', '1'), ('11:23:40', '1')]
}
```

And i would like to have a graph where I display 1s and 0s of each day.

I tried with a heatmap, but it didn't work as expected:

```
#data
day_data = {
    '2023-10-16': [('11:23:35', '1'), ('11:23:40', '1'), ('11:23:45', '1'), ('11:23:50', '1'), ('11:23:55', '1')],
    '2023-10-17': [('11:23:34', '1'), ('11:23:42', '1'), ('11:23:45', '0'), ('11:23:50', '1'), ('11:23:55', '0')],
    '2023-10-18': [('11:23:35', '1'), ('11:23:40', '1')]
}

# Extract unique days and times
days = list(day_data.keys())
times = list(set(time for day in day_data.values() for time, flag in day))

# Create a heatmap based on flag values (0 and 1)
heatmap = np.zeros((len(times), len(days), 3))

for i, day in enumerate(days):
    for j, time in enumerate(times):
        for t, flag in day_data[day]:
            if t == time:
                if flag == '0':
                    heatmap[j, i] = [1, 0, 0]  # Red for flag 0
                else:
                    heatmap[j, i] = [0, 1, 0]  # Green for flag 1

# Plot the heatmap
plt.imshow(heatmap, interpolation="nearest", aspect="auto")
plt.yticks(np.arange(len(times)), times)
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(days)), days, rotation=90, fontsize=10)
plt.xlabel("Day")
plt.ylabel("Time")

plt.title("Checks")
plt.show()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you want them to be evenly spaced in time or simply care about the data provided. We can easily extract the right date and time using the standard library `datetime` module. To put everything into one array, we can then simply do:

```
all_times = []
all_vals = []

for date, data in day_data.items():
    formatted_date = datetime.date.fromisoformat(date)
    times = [datetime.time.fromisoformat(data_point[0]) for data_point in data]
    date_times = [datetime.datetime.combine(formatted_date, time) for time in times]
    data_vals = [int(data_point[1]) for data_point in data]
    all_times.extend(date_times)
    all_vals.extend(data_vals)
```

We can then make a bar plot: [image: bar plot]

using the code

```
plt.bar([dt.isoformat() for dt in all_times], all_vals)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Alternatively, we can create a line graph: [image: line graph]

With the code:

```
plt.plot([dt.isoformat() for dt in all_times], all_vals)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This is the closest I can get from the description of your question. If you want another representation and e.g. a consistent timescale, just let me know and I will modify the code according to your specifications. I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think this is the best solution.

Comment: If you are happy with my solution I would really appreciate if you accept (and maybe upvote) it :)